# Why is this code keep collapsing? It always let Mathmatica not respond even when the memory was 60% in use

Tags: plotting, manipulate

### Messages:

*Coordinate $CellContext`  intersections[3] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.*

*Coordinate $CellContext`intersections[Rational[-17, 10]] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form*

*Coordinate $CellContext`intersections[Rational[-1, 2]] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.*

```
sols3[x_, a_] := y /. Solve[x^2 + (y - a)^2 == 9, y];
sols2[x_, a_] := y /. Solve[y == a x^2, y];
intersections[a_] := {x, y} /. 
Solve[{x^2 + (y - a)^2 == 9 && y == a x^2}, {x, y}, Reals]
Manipulate[
Column@{Plot[
Evaluate@Flatten[{sols3[x, a], sols2[x, a]}], {x, -20, 20}, 
PlotRange -> 20 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, BaseStyle -> Thick, 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[intersections[a]]}, 
AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300], 
Column@intersections[a]}, {{a, 3}, -3, 3, 1/10}]
```

**I have 8GB RAM in my laptop. I don't think it's the problem of my pc. I use Mathematica 12.0.0.0 on Windows 10**

*When I typed in `?intersections`, I got this in the output:*

***intersections[a_] := {x, y} /.Solve[{x^2 + (y - a)^2 == 9 && y == a x^2}, {x, y}, Reals]
  Full name "Global`intersections"***

Comment: You might try clearing the kernel.  It works for me without alteration on M12, windows 10, 32 GB ram.

Comment: @BillWatts , You should let  let Mathmatica 12 play the animation for at least 10 mins

Comment: "play the animation"? "at least 10 mins"?? These are not mentioned in the question. -- Now it's been running 10+ min, using < 150MB RAM, and no problems...

Comment: @MichaelE2, It take 1267.6MB Memory for just this animation to run on my laptop. Have you seen pop-up messages ? "Coordinate $CellContext` intersections[3] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form."

Comment: No, it runs like a charm. -- `intersections[3]` suggests that `intersections` is not defined (as shown).  Could it have gotten cleared somehow?  What happens if you execute "`? intersections`"?

Comment: @MichaelE2 , when I type in your `?intersections`,   
 I got `Missing["UnknownSymbol", "intersections"]` in the output.

Comment: @MichaelE2, that's when I put it on the last line because I many other codes between these 2 codes. However, when I put `?intersections` right after it, I get a totally different result which has already been displayed in my latest edit

Comment: It's been running for me for two hours with no problems.  Do you have other background processes running that may be eating your memory?  8 GB is not a lot of ram nowadays.

Comment: @BillWatts, _Do you run any other `Manipulate` and `Plot`codes in this Notebook?_

Comment: No, I just tried yours and it worked fine.